# SwiftにてUIImageViewをTap検知後、詳細画面に遷移したい

Tags: swift, storyboard

storyboardにてUIimageViewを２つ設定し、それぞれ同じ画像を設定しています。
そこにtagでそれぞれ1,2を設定しています。

```
@IBOutlet weak var iv2: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var iv: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var img = UIImage(named:"paint 2.png")
    iv.image = img
    iv2.image = img
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        println(touch.view.tag)
        switch(touch.view.tag){
        case 1:
            break
        case 2:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

現在の結果としてはUIImageViewがtapされたら1,2がLOGに出力され、それ以外を押したら０が出力されます。

行いたいこととしては、UIImageVIewをタップしたときに次の画面に遷移し、そのタップされた画像の大きい画像を出したいです。
詳細画面のようなものです。
お願いします。

Answer (score 3):

手法はいくつかありますが、[UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer),[UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html)を利用するパターンを検討してみてください。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let img = UIImage(named:"paint 2.png")
    iv.image = img
    iv2.image = img

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action "didClickImageView:")
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    iv2.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func didClickImageView(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let imageView = recognizer.view as? UIImageView {
        let image = imageView.image
        let nextViewController = /** 次のUIViewControllerのインスタンス */
        nextViewController.image = iamge
        /** netViewController への遷移 */
    }
}
```